# How to structure meteor app for testing

Tags: node.js, testing, meteor, meteor-velocity

I'm reading through the online book [Meteor Testing](http://www.meteortesting.com/) and am a bit concerned about how it says you should structure your app. It says to create an object in the global namespace called "App" and append submodules as needed, like this:

```
App = {
    Services: {
        func1: [some function]
        func2: [some function]
        ...
    },
    Collections: {
        func1: [some function]
        func2: [some function]
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

My concerns are:

1. Will this negatively impact the security of my application?
2. Where and when should I defined functions within the app namespace? Adding all of them in one place would quickly get overwhelming.
3. Should I do this for all of the functions I want to unit test? If not, how do I access functions that I have defined within the scope of a template's javascript file?

If any of you could point me to additional resources on testing in meteor, I'd love to take a look at what other people suggest. Thanks.

Comment: Hi. I'm the author of the book. This chapter leaked out before completion! I will shortly be posting an update that tells you how to address points 2 and 3. There's no issue with point 1, but I'll let others answer that :)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for response. Loving the book, btw, it's been very helpful. I had one other unrelated question, which I also posted on the meteortesting site. Are we able to use "Meteor.stubMethods" yet? I wasn't able to use it, and I'm pretty sure I have the most up to date version of velocity.

Comment: Right, I've not updated the Velocity helpers with the chapter! I released the book update and forgot to block this chapter. Oops! I'll update here when I'm done. And thanks :)

Comment: No problem. Looking forward to all the upcoming chapters/updates.

Comment: @Xolv.io I posted an answer below, but I'd love to hear your two cents on it.

Comment: Updated,should now work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could sprinkle the definitions of all your functions among different files, but obviously load order would be important. I'd recommend creating a Meteor package for your project that would define all these functions and other globals needed, and then `api.export('App')` or `api.export('App', 'client')` (depending on your needs).

Comment: This is correct, to create a core package. The chapter will say exactly this shortly :)

Comment: @Xolv.io Cool! And thanks for your contribution to the Meteor community, Sam!

Comment: Just be mindful that the core package should only contain the namespaces. The implementation of the services should live in the app (or in other packages that depend on the core package). This will give you the best separation of concerns

Comment: @Xolv.io So, using the book as an example, you're saying the definition of the `UserService.prototype.authenticate` function should _not_ be in the package, but rather in the app code itself?

Comment: Yes, under `/services/user/server/user-service-server.js` - or if you are a package lover you can create a user-service package and do it there. This is our opinionated way of doing it based on our experience for the best separation of concerns

Comment: What about load order? If I put functions in `/services/user/server/user-service-server.js`, how can I be sure those functions will be available in another part of my app?